# check if two tables are equal

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive

I have two tables with the same structure.
how can I check if all the rows in these two are equal?
i.e. that each row in first table exists in the other one and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from Jeff's blog is relevant for Hive: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx.

> "The basic idea is: if we GROUP the union of two tables on all columns, then if the two tables are identical all groups will result in a COUNT(*) of 2. But for any rows that are not completely matched on any column in the GROUP BY clause, the COUNT(*) will be 1 -- and those are the ones we want.  We also need to add a column to each part of the UNION to indicate which table each row comes from, otherwise there is no way to distinguish between which row comes from which table."

An improved solution for handling duplicates is posted as a comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx#3155 
(Reproducing the code as it is from the comment posted originally by the user "Perry")

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
  FROM
  (
   SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, COUNT(*) NDUPS, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
    FROM Table1 A GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, COUNT(*) NDUPS, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
    FROM Table2 B
    GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
   ) tmp
   GROUP BY NDUPS, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: May you post a summary for each links ? This way, information won't be lost if links become broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one. I'm not sure if there's a better or simpler way to do this, but something like this might work:

Assuming you have two tables, t1 and t2, and they each have two columns, c1 and c2

```
create view t1_counts
as select c1, c2, count(*) as num
from t1
group by c1, c2;

create view t2_counts
as select c1, c2, count(*) as num
from t2
group by c1, c2;

select t1_counts.c1, t1_counts.c2, t1_counts.num, t2_counts.num
from t1_counts full outer join t2_counts on (t1_counts.c1 = t2_counts.c1 and t1_counts.c2 = t2_counts.c2)
where t1_counts.num != t2_counts.num;
```

The output will be empty if the two tables are equal.